# 'npm ERR! signal SIGTERM' with DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 in gitlab docker runner

Tags: docker, npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-buildkit

My gitlab docker runner is based on image *docker:20-dind*.

When I use Buildkit (by setting DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1 as variable in the gitlab-ci.yml) the build fails with

```
#25 [be-spaces 3/4] RUN npm run build:be-spaces
#25 sha256:ba2dbcfd10c7edce9435cadcf8cdc69c4ab0291dbaf7ca134a8feff8ba3de303
#25 0.814 
#25 0.814 > ba-fem-nx-workspace@0.5.1 build:be-spaces
#25 0.814 > nx run be-spaces:build:production
#25 0.814 
#25 1.858 npm ERR! path /app
#25 1.862 npm ERR! command failed
#25 1.862 npm ERR! signal SIGTERM
#25 1.862 npm ERR! command sh -c nx run be-spaces:build:production
#25 1.866 
#25 1.866 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#25 1.866 npm ERR!     /home/node/.npm/_logs/2023-07-03T19_57_08_863Z-debug-0.log
#25 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm run build:be-spaces]: exit code: 1
------
 > [be-spaces 3/4] RUN npm run build:be-spaces:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm run build:be-spaces]: exit code: 1
```

Without buildkit the build job succeeds.

I have different (similar) jobs in this multistage dockerfile, all but this one job succeed with buildkit!

I changed the command to `RUN npm run build:be-spaces || (sleep 30000 && exit 1)` to sleep in case of the failing command to be able to docker exec into the runner container. I thought I will find the `/home/node/.npm/_logs/....log` file and the built code there but that's not the case. I find two running containers `runner-...-build` and `runner-...-docker-0` but I don't find any relevant data inside.

Any idea how to debug this?